# Display own advertisement images in my android application

Tags: android, ads

What is best way to display my own ads images ,( which are stored in my remote server) and display them in my android application.

is it possible using admob or any other libraries or i have to make it manually using an imageview inside a layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use [House Ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210442?hl=en) to display your own ads. You can also create a web service backend for your ad images: you can either poll this to get the ad (image and url to link to) or you can push the ad (image&link) to devices via something like [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: but does House Ads supports the retrieval of the images from remote server.

Comment: You have to upload images for use in the ad. You can create your own web service to either push to devices or for app to poll image ads from.